# How can I make my Makefile build to the obj/ folder, not the src/ folder?

Tags: c, makefile, directory, subdirectory

I am extending an old school project, and I have the Makefile the course staff made for us. I have reorganized the directory structure of the project like this.

```
+-----obj
|
+-----src
|     |
|     +-Makefile
|     +-allocator.h
|     +-debug_break.h
|     +-rbtree_clrs.c
|     +-rbtree_linked.c
|     +-rbtree_stack.c
|     +-rbtree_topdown.c
|     +-rbtree_unified.c
|     +-segment.c
|     +-segment.h
|     +-test_harness.c
|     +-my_optional_program.c
|
+------scripts
```

The Makefile currently prepends the heap allocators I wrote (files starting with `rbtree_`) with either `test_` or `my_optional_program` and puts them in the same directory as the Makefile. I can then run my different heap allocator implementations on the scripts in the `scripts` folder. Instead, I want this:

```
+-----obj
|     +-my_optional_program_rbtree_clrs
|     +-my_optional_program_rbtree_linked
|     +-my_optional_program_rbtree_stack
|     +-my_optional_program_rbtree_topdown
|     +-my_optional_program_rbtree_unified
|     +-test_rbtree_clrs
|     +-test_rbtree_linked
|     +-test_rbtree_stack
|     +-test_rbtree_topdown
|     +-test_rbtree_unified
|
+-----src
|     |
|     +-Makefile
|     +-allocator.h
|     +-debug_break.h
|     +-rbtree_clrs.c
|     +-rbtree_linked.c
|     +-rbtree_stack.c
|     +-rbtree_topdown.c
|     +-rbtree_unified.c
|     +-segment.c
|     +-segment.h
|     +-test_harness.c
|     +-my_optional_program.c
|     
+------scripts
```

What do I need to add or change in the Makefile so that it will build to the `obj/` folder?

```
# They had us try different optimization levels here (-O0, -O2, etc).
rbtree_clrs.o: CFLAGS += -O0
rbtree_unified.o: CFLAGS += -O0
rbtree_linked.o: CFLAGS += -O0
rbtree_stack.o: CFLAGS += -O0
rbtree_topdown.o: CFLAGS += -O0

ALLOCATORS = rbtree_clrs rbtree_unified rbtree_stack rbtree_linked rbtree_topdown
PROGRAMS = $(ALLOCATORS:%=test_%)
MY_PROGRAMS = $(ALLOCATORS:%=my_optional_program_%)

all:: $(PROGRAMS) $(MY_PROGRAMS)

# I had to use gcc-11 on mac to be able to build this project.
UNAME := $(shell uname)
ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
CC = gcc-11
else
CC = gcc
endif

CFLAGS = -g3 -std=gnu99 -Wall $$warnflags -fcf-protection=none -fno-pic -no-pie
export warnflags = -Wfloat-equal -Wtype-limits -Wpointer-arith -Wlogical-op -Wshadow -Winit-self -fno-diagnostics-show-option
LDFLAGS =
LDLIBS =

$(PROGRAMS): test_%:%.o segment.c test_harness.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(MY_PROGRAMS): my_optional_program_%:my_optional_program.c %.o segment.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean::
    rm -f $(PROGRAMS) $(MY_PROGRAMS) *.o callgrind.out.*

.PHONY: clean all

.INTERMEDIATE: $(ALLOCATORS:%=%.o)
```

Update: This Makefile has solved the issue. I took [Renaud Pacalet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1773798/renaud-pacalet)'s Makefile (thanks!) and adjusted the paths to achieve the desired result. It seems not going up one level in the directories was an issue. Then I had to add the path I wanted to the `ALLOCATORS` in the `PROGRAMS` variable. I have no idea if this is how it should be done but it worked. I can update this if there is a better way.

```
SRCDIR = ../src
OBJDIR = ../obj
SRC := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
OBJ := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRC))

# They had us try different optimization levels here (-O0, -O2, etc).
$(filter $(OBJDIR)/rbtree_%.o,$(OBJ)): CFLAGS += -O0

ALLOCATORS = rbtree_clrs rbtree_unified rbtree_stack rbtree_linked rbtree_topdown
PROGRAMS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/test_,$(ALLOCATORS))
MY_PROGRAMS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/my_optional_program_,$(ALLOCATORS))

all:: $(PROGRAMS) $(MY_PROGRAMS)

# I had to use gcc-11 on mac to be able to build this project.
UNAME := $(shell uname)
ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
CC = gcc-11
else
CC = gcc
endif

CFLAGS = -g3 -std=gnu99 -Wall $$warnflags -fcf-protection=none -fno-pic -no-pie
export warnflags = -Wfloat-equal -Wtype-limits -Wpointer-arith -Wlogical-op -Wshadow -Winit-self -fno-diagnostics-show-option
LDFLAGS =
LDLIBS =

$(OBJ): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(PROGRAMS): $(OBJDIR)/test_%: $(OBJDIR)/%.o segment.c test_harness.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(MY_PROGRAMS): $(OBJDIR)/my_optional_program_%: my_optional_program.c $(OBJDIR)/%.o segment.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean::
    rm -f $(PROGRAMS) $(MY_PROGRAMS) $(OBJ) callgrind.out.*
```

Comment: Don't do `ifeq($(UNAME),Darwin)`....  Test features, not the platform.  It seems that what you actually care about is whether or not you have `gcc-11` or not. Don't assume that Darwin will provide the tool; check if you have the tool!

Comment: I think I understand but this was just to force my laptop to build this correctly. Mac seems to use `gcc` as an alias for `clang` and `clang` had some issues with this project that I didn't know how to fix. So on mac I downloaded `gcc`, put it before `clang` on my `$PATH` and forced my mac to use `gcc` with `gcc-11`, otherwise it would still use `gcc` as an alias for `clang`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a compilation rule so make uses its implicit rule for compilation which puts the object files in the same directory as the source files.

Simply add a rule of your own and rework a bit all references to object files:

```
OBJDIR := ../obj
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRC))

# They had us try different optimization levels here (-O0, -O2, etc).
$(filter $(OBJDIR)/rbtree_%.o,$(OBJ)): CFLAGS += -O0

ALLOCATORS = rbtree_clrs rbtree_unified rbtree_stack rbtree_linked rbtree_topdown
PROGRAMS = $(ALLOCATORS:%=$(OBJDIR)/test_%)
MY_PROGRAMS = $(ALLOCATORS:%=$(OBJDIR)/my_optional_program_%)

all:: $(PROGRAMS) $(MY_PROGRAMS)

# I had to use gcc-11 on mac to be able to build this project.
UNAME := $(shell uname)
ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
CC = gcc-11
else
CC = gcc
endif

CFLAGS = -g3 -std=gnu99 -Wall $$warnflags -fcf-protection=none -fno-pic -no-pie
export warnflags = -Wfloat-equal -Wtype-limits -Wpointer-arith -Wlogical-op -Wshadow -Winit-self -fno-diagnostics-show-option
LDFLAGS =
LDLIBS =

$(OBJ): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o '$@' '$<'

$(PROGRAMS): $(OBJDIR)/test_%: $(OBJDIR)/%.o segment.c test_harness.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(MY_PROGRAMS): $(OBJDIR)/my_optional_program_%: my_optional_program.c $(OBJDIR)/%.o segment.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean::
    rm -f $(PROGRAMS) $(MY_PROGRAMS) $(OBJ) callgrind.out.*
```

Note that you should also manage the dependencies between object and header files (which the above does not, just like the original version). If it's simple enough you'll easily modify the proposed Makefile. Else consider reading [this very interesting post about Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) by the current GNU make main maintainer.

Comment: Thank you! I will work on dependency management. However, for now I am getting the following error message: `make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/rbtree_clrs.o', needed by 'test_rbtree_clrs'.  Stop.`. I have double checked all `.c` files mentioned are in the `src/` directory, the `obj/` folder is created, and that the Makefile uses tabs and not spaces. Do you have any other tips to get the first clean build?

Comment: My bad, there was a typo in: `OBJ := $(patsubst src/%.c,obj/%.c,$(SRC))`. It should of course be: `OBJ := $(patsubst src/%.c,obj/%.o,$(SRC))`. I fix it in my answer.

Comment: With a few more slight tweaks I made it work and updated my question if you want to see what I changed.

Comment: Ooops, sorry again, I didn't see that your Makefile was in the `src` directory and that you invoke make from there (I personally usually put the Makefile and invoke make from the top). Let me fix this.